# Is this custom JSON parser in a Rust realtime app as efficient as it gets?

Tags: json, assembly, rust, x86, arm64

For a realtime app, I need to parse JSON coming from a streaming HTTP response in the hotpath, every nanosecond counts.
Since I know that this JSON will always have the same format, just different values, I can parse this JSON very efficiently not using `serde-json`.
An example JSON response looks like this:

```
[{"prelude":"an_unimportant_ascii_string",
"data":{"a_value":"33.09", "a_value_date":"date_to_be_ignored", "a_value_ext":"300",
"b_value":"2.2", "b_value_date":"date_to_be_ignored", "b_value_ext":null, "id":integer_to_be_ignored}},
{"prelude": "...", "data": {"like": "before"}}, ...]
```

As you can see all values are ASCII. `a_value` and `b_value` are always f32 inside a string, `a_value_ext` and `b_value_ext` are always i32 inside a string *or null !*. The other keys can be ignored. The order will always be like this and keys won't disappear.

At first, there is a trait which i32 and f32 implement so I can treat both in the same way.

```
trait ParseNumber: Default {
    fn parse(bytes: &[u8]) -> Self;
    fn minus_one() -> Self;
}

impl ParseNumber for i32 {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn parse(bytes: &[u8]) -> Self {
        byte_to_str(bytes).parse().unwrap()
    }

    #[inline(always)]
    fn minus_one() -> Self {
        -1
    }
}

impl ParseNumber for f32 {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn parse(bytes: &[u8]) -> Self {
        byte_to_str(bytes).parse().unwrap()
    }

    #[inline(always)]
    fn minus_one() -> Self {
        -1f32
    }
}

#[inline(always)]
const fn byte_to_str(bytes: &[u8]) -> &str {
    unsafe { std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(bytes) }
}
```

The entrypoint is a function which makes a request using hyper and receives a streaming, infinite response:

```
use memchr::{memchr, memchr_iter};

pub async fn receive_data() -> Result<(), StreamingError> {
        
    //let client = ....
    //let request = ....

    let mut response = client.request(request).await?;

    while let Some(Ok(frame)) = response.body_mut().frame().await {
        if let Some(data) = frame.data_ref() {
            process_frame(data).await?;
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Which is then processed by `process_frame`. This is around 200 times faster than what I had with `serde-json`. It makes use of the `memchr` crate which employs SIMD under the hood. For the `ParseNumber` implementations I also used `fast-float` and `atoi-simd` previously, but they did not prove to be faster. For a regular JSON response this takes ~160ns on my machine (Apple M2).
Please note that for the nullable values, the last quote is missing in the byte strings. The byte strings are constants in my actual code, but written out here for transparency's sake.

```
#[inline(always)]
async fn process_frame(mut data: &[u8]) -> Result<(), StreamingError> {

    while let (true, bytes) = find_pattern(data, br#""a_value":""#) {
        let (a_value_str, a_value, bytes) = extract::<f32>(bytes, b'"');
        let (_, bytes) = find_pattern(bytes, br#""a_value_ext":"#);
        let (a_value_ext_str, a_value_ext, bytes) = extract_nullable::<i32>(bytes, b'"');
        let (_, bytes) = find_pattern(bytes, br#""b_value":""#);
        let (b_value_str, b_value, bytes) = extract::<f32>(bytes, b'"');
        let (_, bytes) = find_pattern(bytes, br#""b_value_ext":"#);
        let (b_value_ext_str, b_value_ext, bytes) = extract_nullable::<i32>(bytes, b'"');
        data = bytes;

        // let processed_data = handle data extracted above into struct
        // call method which also is inline(always) with this struct

        // if we have another json object, continue extracting
        if bytes.len() < VALID_MIN_LENGTH {
            break;
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

/// tries to find the first char of the pattern and then the whole pattern
#[inline(always)]
fn find_pattern<'a>(bytes: &'a [u8], pattern: &[u8]) -> (bool, &'a [u8]) {
    let pattern_len = pattern.len();
    let first_char = unsafe { *pattern.get_unchecked(0) };

    unsafe {
        for i in memchr_iter(first_char, bytes.get_unchecked(..bytes.len() - pattern_len + 1)) {
            let new_end_index = i + pattern_len;
            if bytes.get_unchecked(i..new_end_index) == pattern {
                return (true, bytes.get_unchecked(new_end_index..));
            }
        }
    }
    (false, bytes)
}

///extracts the number inside the string
#[inline(always)]
fn extract<T: ParseNumber>(bytes: &[u8], pattern: u8) -> (&[u8], T, &[u8]) {
    match memchr(pattern, bytes) {
        Some(i) => unsafe {
            let value = bytes.get_unchecked(..i);
            (value, T::parse(value), bytes.get_unchecked(i + 1..))
        },
        None => {
            show_error("Error parsing", bytes);
            (b"-1", T::minus_one(), bytes)
        }
    }
}

//checks if a value is null, otherwise extracts the number in the string
#[inline(always)]
fn extract_nullable<T: ParseNumber>(bytes: &[u8], pattern: u8) -> (&[u8], T, &[u8]) {
    let first_char = unsafe { *bytes.get_unchecked(0) };
    let bytes = match first_char {
        //null
        b'n' => return (b"0", T::default(), unsafe { bytes.get_unchecked(4..) }),
        //a string
        b'"' => unsafe { bytes.get_unchecked(1..) },
        _ => {
            show_error("Can't happen", bytes);
            bytes
        }
    };
    extract(bytes, pattern)
}
```

So my question now is if this is the most efficient way I can parse/extract those values from a JSON byte string in Rust. I am a beginner in Rust, so I might have missed something obvious. Can I optimize for ARM64 (or also X86_64) even more anywhere? Is my heavy use of `#[inline(always)]` justified?

Comment: This would fit better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/simd-lite/simd-json (a Rust port) and the original C++ SIMD JSON (https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson)?  Or is your case specialized for the exact things your application expects to find in its JSON?  (I haven't looked at your code yet.)

Comment: @PitaJ Unfortunately, on codereview, Rust is not very popular, so I posted it here.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the pointer, I'll give it a try but I strongly assume that my tailored solution here is already faster.

Comment: Could well be.  Their big speed claims are for generic stuff like validating, minifying, and UTF-8 checking, which are useful but not what you need.  They might have some useful ideas for ways to use NEON for some things that you might be able to copy; that's more what I had in mind instead of throwing out your existing code and just using that library.

Comment: If everything is so time critical I would suggest to use a different serialization format instead of JSON. Which only works of course if both sides agree - https://github.com/djkoloski/rust_serialization_benchmark

Comment: Since you are willing to cut corners you can parse everything manually. Ideally, you receive your data as `[u8]` without passing from a `str` in the first place. Make four `u8` arrays, one for each pattern, and keep four indices. Scan the data until you have found all four values. For each byte in the data check it against the four patterns according to their index. On a match, increase the index, set it to 0 otherwise. If an index reaches the end, a pattern matched. Skip the `:` char and check for `n`. If it's there, the value is null, save it and repeat. Otherwise you have a `nn.dd` pattern

Comment: you can parse it easily with two accumulators updated char by char (`acc = acc*10 + c - '0'`). When you see a `"` combine the integer accumulator with the (possibly zero) decimal accumulator. You now have parsed a value and you repeat. Note however that you are exposing yourself to the danger of API mutability. Furthermore, if you are fetching this data over the network, parsing won't be the bottleneck.

Comment: KMP search may improve times but it requires preprocessing (I think it can be done once and reused everytime, IIRC).

Comment: @MargaretBloom Nothing is str, everything is [u8] already and the search I'm doing is pretty much what you suggest. I will give a custom accumulator a try and see if it can parse the numbers faster.

Comment: Using a custom accumulator had positive effects, especially for f32. The custom version is around 2.5 times faster than parse() from std. For i32 the improvement is only marginal (10%).